# Haskell - alternating elements from two lists

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, alternating

I'm trying to write a haskell function that takes in two lists of integers and generates a list with elements that have been taken alternatingly from the two lists.

I have the function:

```
blend xs ys
```

An example:

```
blend [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
```

should return

```
[1,4,2,5,3,6]
```

My logic is to zip the two lists together, generating the pairs of alternate elements, then somehow remove them from their tuples.

It's removing them from their tuples that I can't figure out how to implement.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about exchanging the arguments during recursion-descend?

```
blend (x:xs) ys = x:(blend ys xs)
blend _ _ = []
```

You can even generalise this approach for any number of lists (I'll leave this to you) or take the remaining elements of a list if the other is empty:

```
blend _ ys = ys
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to zip, generate lists instead of tuples:

```
concat $ zipWith (\x y -> [x,y]) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
```

Some pointless fun:

```
concat $ zipWith ((flip(:)).(:[])) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
```

Probably the easiest way:

```
import Data.List
concat $ transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 7):

I will assume that this is homework. Provided that you can create the following list (as you said):

```
[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

... you can solve it with 2 functions:

1. You need to convert a tuple `(a, b)` into a list `[a, b]`. Try using pattern matching! This function needs to be applied (aka. mapped) over all elements of the list you have.
2. You will have a list of lists, like `[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]`, so you need a function for concatenating the sublists into one big list.

There are of course other, maybe superior, ways to solve this problem, but it might be a good idea to continue with your original approach.

Comment: I think an answer to a `[homework]` question that continues on in the original direction is particularly helpful (unless the direction was completely wrong, which, in this case, it wasn't).

Answer (score 3):

A solution without using `concat` or explicit recursion:

```
blend l = foldr($)[] . zipWith(.) (map(:)l) . map(:)
```

We can make also make this point-free

```
blend' = (foldr($)[].) . (.map(:)) . zipWith(.) . map(:)
```

---

How it works: first decorate both lists with cons operators

```
\[1,2,3] [4,5,6] -> [1:, 2:, 3:] [4:, 5:, 6:]
```

then we zip this together with function composition

```
-> [(1:).(4:), (2:).(5:), (3:).(6:)]
```

and finally fold the application of all these compositions from the right to the empty list

```
-> (1:).(4:) $ (2:).(5:) $ (3:).(6:) $ [] = 1:4:2:5:3:6:[] = [1,4,2,5,3,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `blend` function seems to be a limited version of `flatZip`. The `flatZip` function is similar but works for any number of lists of varying lengths. Using flatZip to implement blend will cause blend to also support varying lengths by default. Therefore, using a `flatZip` based approach may *not* be the way to go in situations where trimming the input lists to equal length is part of the desired behaviour.

The name `flatZip` refers to "a `zip`ish way of `flatten`ing". Note the *-ish* part though. We can implement the function by composing `concat` with `transpose`. We can add `blend` on top of `flatZip` as syntactic sugar to verify that our implementation matches the desired behaviour.

```hs
import Data.List

flatZip = concat . transpose
flatZip([[1,2],[3],[4,5,6]]) --[1,3,4,2,5,6]

blend xs ys = flatZip [xs, ys]
blend [1,2,3] [4,5,6] --[1,4,2,5,3,6]
```